# How to fix layered navigation error in 3rd party module with category and price filters?

Tags: category, layered-navigation, magento2.3.4, mageplaza

Running Magento 2.3.4 with Webkul Multivendor Marketplace Module and it is having compatibility issues with Mageplaza Ajax Layered navigation.
The layered navigation and ajax filters doesn't seem to work inside the marketplace vendor products view and also the category filters throws an error when selected that I have mentioned below and the price filter doesn't seem to work at all (the URL just changes to ".../?price=from-to" without the selected price range numbers) but other filters like color, size, and custom attribute works.

Here is the error is thrown when selecting category filter:

```
1 exception(s):

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log.
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_renderFilters() called at [app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php:408]
#2 Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->_renderFilters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php:578]
#3 Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter() called at [app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php:196]
#4 Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection->removeAttributeSearch('category_ids') called at [app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php:141]
#5 Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Category->_getItemsData() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php:202]
#6 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->_initItems() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php:159]
#7 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItems() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/AbstractFilter.php:148]
#8 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter->getItemsCount() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Category/AvailabilityFlag.php:33]
#9 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->canShowOptions(array(&Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Category#00000000019c857100000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c857c00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c857b00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c857800000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c857a00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c854800000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855700000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855600000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Price#00000000019c855000000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855d00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855c00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855b00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855a00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855900000000397c6469#)) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Category/AvailabilityFlag.php:23]
#10 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag->isEnabled(&Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category#00000000019c843c00000000397c6469#, array(&Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Category#00000000019c857100000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c857c00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c857b00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c857800000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c857a00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c854800000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855700000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855600000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Price#00000000019c855000000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855d00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855c00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855b00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855a00000000397c6469#, &Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute#00000000019c855900000000397c6469#)) called at [vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/Block/Navigation.php:126]
#11 Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation->canShowBlock() called at [app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/view/frontend/templates/seller/collection/layer/view.phtml:1]
#12 include('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Navigation#00000000019c841600000000397c6469#, '/var/www/html/ap...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1099]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1103]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:673]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:564]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('marketplace_sell...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:540]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('marketplace_sell...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('marketplace_sell...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('marketplace_sell...', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('marketplace_sell...', true) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:524]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml()
#25 call_user_func_array(array(&Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Sellercategory#00000000019c840a00000000397c6469#, 'getChildHtml'), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:82]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->__call('getChildHtml', array()) called at [app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/view/frontend/templates/collectionleft.phtml:18]
#27 include('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Sellercategory#00000000019c840a00000000397c6469#, '/var/www/html/ap...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1099]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1103]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:673]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:564]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('marketplace_sell...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:540]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('marketplace_sell...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('marketplace_sell...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('marketplace_sell...', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('marketplace_sell...', true) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:520]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('marketplace_sell...') called at [app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/view/frontend/templates/collectionview.phtml:45]
#40 include('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Webkul\Marketplace\Block\Collection\Interceptor#00000000019c843600000000397c6469#, '/var/www/html/ap...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/ap...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1099]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1103]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:673]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:564]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('marketplace_sell...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:540]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('marketplace_sell...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('marketplace_sell...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('marketplace_sell...', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('marketplace_sell...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#67 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#69 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#71 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#75 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#76 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:592]
#77 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#78 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#79 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:495]
#80 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#81 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:961]
#82 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#83 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#84 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#85 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:494]
#86 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#87 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000019c82cd00000000397c6469#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#88 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000019c82cd00000000397c6469#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#89 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000019c82cd00000000397c6469#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#90 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000019c82cd00000000397c6469#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#91 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000019c82cd00000000397c6469#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'), array('updateBodyClass'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:39]
#92 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000019c82cd00000000397c6469#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#93 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#94 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#00000000019c82cb00000000397c6469#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

The system logs just say:

```
[2021-10-04 02:39:18] main.ERROR: Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log. [] []
```

The Webkul Marketplace Logs doesn't mention anything.
Is there a way to fix it or maybe disable Mageplaza layered navigation inside the marketplace module?

Comment: have you checked the error.log of apache too? (In case that's an error 500)

Comment: Already checked. Its not a 500 error.

Comment: Your best bet is to check line 408 in Fulltext/Collection.php and see what it's trying to do